# Let $f$ be a complex function defined on an open ball $U$. If $\sup |f(z)|=|f(z_0)|$ and if $f'(z_0)$ exists, is $f'(z_0)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, derivatives, proof-writing

I'm reading Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis and I'm wondering if the following theorem can be generalized to complex functions:

**Theorem:** Let $f$ be a real function on $[a,b]$. If $f$ has a local maximum (or minimum) at $x_0$, and if $f'(x_0)$ exists, then $f'(x_0)=0$.

---

I've read about the Maximum modulus principle, and even though I admittedly don't know much about complex functions, this principle doesn't seem to resolve my question since I'm only requiring that $f'$ be defined on $z_0$, and thus $f$ need not be holomorphic on any set containing $z_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the above is kind of weird since the function cannot be differentiable in a neighborhood of $z_0$ (without being in the trivial constant case), the answer is still yes as follows. Wlog we can assume $z_0=0, |f(0)| \ne 0$ (consider $g(z)=f(z+z_0)$) and then by considering $\alpha f$ (doesn't change hypothesis/conclusion) for some $|\alpha|=1$ we can assume $f(0) >0$ and by scaling $f(0)=1$ so the problem reduces to showing that:

if $\frac{f(z)-1}{z} \to A+iB, z \to 0, |f(z)| \le 1, |z| <r$ then $A=B=0$

But now take $z=x \in (-r,r)$ and notice that the hypothesis implies $\Re \frac{f(x)-1}{x} \to A, x \to 0$ or equivalently $\frac{\Re f(x)-1}{x} \to A, x \to 0, x \in (-r,r)$

Since $\Re f(x) \le |f(x)| \le 1$ the numerator is non-positive, while the denominator takes both plus and minus signs, which clearly forces $A=0$

Similarly with $z=ix$, $\frac{f(ix)-1}{ix} \to iB, x \to 0, x \in (-r,r)$ so  $\frac{f(ix)-1}{x} \to -B, x \to 0, x \in (-r,r)$ and taking real parts and repeating the reasoning forces $B=0$ Done!

Comment: This is excellent. The only part I don't understand is why $[f(x)-1]/x$ and $[f(ix)-1]/ix$ must tend to $A$ and $iB$ respectively.

Comment: the real part of $(f(x)-1)/x$ tends to $A$ and since $x$ real, this is same as $(\Re f(x)-1)/x \to A$; for the second part we now know that $A=0$ so $[f(ix)-1]/ix \to iB$ by hypothesis